# Is my female guppy pregnant? About how far along if so. I just bought her a week ago

Tags: aquarium

[image]

I purchased this female guppy about a week ago and I think she’s pregnant. If she is how far along do you think she is? Is it true they will eat all of their babies?

Comment: guppys are always pregnant unless they are male.and yes the babies might be eaten so provide hiding places for them in your tank like plants and decorations.we have lots of pregnant guppy questions so you will probably find an answer among them,wellcome to pets.

Comment: @trondhansen, agree while this is a better picture of the guppy.